# Override plugin images so that they are not removed when the plugin is updated

Tags: plugins, child-theme

Is it possible?

It's the x in this page. the one for removing the composizioni corali filter. It is in plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/img/ with the name delete.png

https://www.digitalmnemes.it/catalogo/?swoof=1&w3tc_note=flush_all&product_cat=composizioni-corali

I've added a delete.png file in mychildtheme/woocommerce-products-filter/img/ but it didn't work.
Is my method supposed to work or is there another way of doing it? I really want to change it because it doesn't fit my theme at all and it looks like it comes from a 2004 computer.

Comment: the part is not easy to customise, you can try with the filter [do_shortcode_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/)

Comment: Unfortunately my php knowledge is limited to variables atm... I've read the description but I have no idea what to do with that code ^^".

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, but only for the woof woocommerce attribute filter plugin. I'll just leave it here for anyone who might need it. 
there are these rules in the front.css file in plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/css which have to do with the icon.

```
.woof_products_top_panel li span {
    padding-right: 16px;
    background: url(../img/delete.png);
    background-size: 12px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:
```

Where there is "../img/delete.png" I can use any url I want, making sure not to have that ../ and that I have https:// otherwise the path will always be relative to the woocommerce-products-filter folder. I just have to make a folder for the plugin in the child theme (themes/nameofmychildtheme/woocommerce-products-filter/css/), copy the front.css file there, change the code so that the url points to the image I want to use. 
There. You can permanently change your delete.png image in woof woocommerce filters.

GGWP.